# Best 'hidden' CiviCRM features?

Tags: best-practice

Does anyone have any really good 'hidden' CiviCRM features / easter eggs that you don't see enough of the community taking advantage of?

We just wrote an article about [a few we know about](https://www.compuco.io/blog/the-5-most-useful-hidden-features-in-civicrm) and were wondering if anyone else had some even better ones?

Comment: Nice write up of those features. A new one in there for me.

Comment: FWIW, this is not really the type of question that stackexchange is aiming to support. As this stackoverflow help indicates, you should avoid asking chatty, open-ended questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask .

Answer (score 5):

Custom search proximity search, then use the actions dropdown to map contacts on a map. (Requires setting up mapping at google or openstreetmaps, but worth it.)

I think searchkit is close to having proximity search too, but right now I think it's only in the custom search.

You can also map contacts from any regular search result too, but proximity radius seems the most useful for mapping.

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky because some of the "best" hidden features are of niche interest, or require extensions.

For strictly core "hidden" features, I'd suggest the batch accounting integration, event badges, and of course Search Kit and Form Builder are still hidden to most users.

Also: Override any settings in `civicrm.settings.php`, sending CiviReports out via email on a scheduled basis, multi-site, invoicing, the user dashboard (`/civicrm/user`, not the "home" Civi screen), contribution premiums and PCPs, Quick Search based on custom fields, and Search Views to customize your search results (in non-Search Kit searches).